# Programs can't connect to pulseaudio unless I kill and restart the daemon

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, daemon

The pulseaudio daemon is running after startup, but I can't change the volume because pamixer and pavucontrol can't connect to the daemon. I have to kill and restart the daemon to get everything working. Sound plays before I kill and restart the daemon, but I can't change the volume.

I'm running Arch Linux x86_64.

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem. You can check with `ps aux` under what user the daemon runs. And use strace -e open,openat,connect pamixer to see which Unix socket they try to access

Comment: Does it seem that I should add my user to the audio group if I do find something wrong with permissions?

Comment: I have seen this happening, too. In my case the sound was not played through `pulseaudio`: VLC somehow detected `pulseaudio` being sick and played the audio through different means.

Restarting the daemon and VLC fixed it every time.

Answer (score 1):

pam should at console login give your user membership in the audio group (i believe.)

This in contrast to if you instead would have used ssh.

You should look in the pam chain for login (or xdb/gdm.)
It seems that logind (systemd's logind ?) and udev to grant access to the sound device.